# How to coloring specific edge of Container border in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone I want to coloring only top right side and left bottom side of my container
I didn't find a way to do that with flutter

```
Container( 
          child: Text("Your Text"),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),

          ),
          boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: primaryColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                spreadRadius: 4,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),

            ],
        ),
```

the below Image describe what I want to achieve.
Please help me I'm stuck with it since two days ago

[image]

Comment: you need a custom `Decoration`, something similar to https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L40

Comment: Thanks very much bro.
I used CornerDecoration class,but I want to make rounded  corner how can I get that or where I should edit to get what I need

Comment: Please look at the result :
https://i.ibb.co/ZTht3PV/stroke-flutter.jpg 
I want to make it rounded border what should I edit and use to make that ?

Comment: you have to change `paint` method

Comment: What I need to change I don't have a good experience, so I will be glad if you guid me
Thanks in advance

Comment: var topLeftCornerRect = Alignment.topLeft.inscribe(cornerSide.topLeft, rect);
In above code which class shuold I use instead of Alignment where Alignment.topLeft.inscribe return Rect I need a RRect to make rounded corners ?

Comment: check [arcToPoint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/arcToPoint.html) method

Comment: Sorry bro. for alot of my question but I don't know where can I use arcToPoint method ?

Comment: did you see that original class draws two lines as a corner? your job is to draw a rounded corner, so replace two calls of `Path.lineTo` with `Path.arcToPoint`

Comment: is that required to edit also in i iterator of offset or just I need to edit in while blocks ?

Comment: you can just modify `while` loop but better is to change the list of `Offset`s too as it does not need 12 offsets but only 8

Answer (score 3):

One way you can try is by using `CustomPainter`. Here we first draw a normal rectangle with rounded corners. And then on top of that redraw the 2 corners with red color.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;
    double r = 15;                      //<-- corner radius
    
    Paint blackPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    Paint redPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5;
    
    RRect fullRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(w/2, h/2), width: w, height: h),
          Radius.circular(r),
        );
    
    Path topRightArc = Path()
      ..moveTo(w - r, 0)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(w, r), radius: Radius.circular(r));
    
    Path bottomLeftArc = Path()
      ..moveTo(r, h)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(0, h - r), radius: Radius.circular(r));
    
    canvas.drawRRect(fullRect, blackPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(topRightArc, redPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(bottomLeftArc, redPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: no, this is a job for custom `Decoration`, check https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L7 for some working examples